# Why can I not reuse temp tables in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

Here's some sample code:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList

create table #TempList (
   ID int,
   Name varchar(20)
)

insert into #TempList values (1, 'Alpha')
insert into #TempList values (2, 'Beta')
insert into #TempList values (3, 'Gamma')
insert into #TempList values (4, 'Delta')
insert into #TempList values (5, 'Omega')

select * from #TempList

if object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList
drop table #TempList

create table #TempList (
   ID_New int,
   AnotherID int,
   Name_New varchar(40)
)

insert into #TempList values (100, 110, 'Orange')
insert into #TempList values (101, 111, 'Red')
insert into #TempList values (102, 112, 'Purple')
insert into #TempList values (103, 113, 'Blue')
insert into #TempList values (104, 114, 'Green')

select * from #TempList
```

This yields the following error:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
There is already an object named '#TempList' in the database.
```

Am I not able to re-use the same temp table name within the same SQL script?  Is there a way to re-use the same temp table name?

Thanks.

Comment: There is also global ##tempTables which can be used in different queryis under one connection, You can declare global temp table by naming it with ## at begining

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList
drop table #TempList

create table #TempList (
```

to

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList
drop table #TempList

GO;

create table #TempList (
```

SQL Server query optimizer gets confused.

It sees that you create the same table second time.
Note that table drop (as well as create) has probabilistic outcome,
the result will be known only at run-time
(not upon syntax control or query exec plan creation aka "compilation" in jargon of SQL Server)

Comment: I dunno why nobody answered before because it is classic illustration why/when to use GO at all. Another way to avoid error is just to execute statement by statement

Comment: I am not allowed to write GO in Stored Procedure, how can i do this stored procedure in SQL server 2012

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a parser error to me.  I'm betting it sees the two create table statements creating the same table and throws the error, regardless of the drop statement.  Breaking it up with a go statement works fine though.

```
create table #Temp (ID int)
insert into #Temp (ID)
select 1 union all select 2

select ID from #Temp

drop table #Temp
go
create table #Temp (ID int)

insert into #Temp (ID)
select 10 union all select 11

select ID from #Temp

drop table #Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with scoping and `#temp` tables.  Since you can have two connections with the same named `#temp` table, the metadata doesn't directly refer to it by the name you specify.

The behavior is explained in [this blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/29/sql-server-fix-error-msg-2714-level-16-state-6-there-is-already-an-object-named-temp-in-the-database/) pretty thoroughly.

You need to run a different query using a `LIKE` comparison to remove the `#temp` table:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#templist%')
DROP TABLE #templist
CREATE TABLE #templist...
```

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
There is already an object named '#templist' in the database.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Drop the table when you are done using it. :)

Comment: But he *is* dropping the table...isn't he?

Comment: Yes.  Tried two different ways.  For some reason, it always gives me the posted error when attempting to recreate the same temp table name again within the same script/session.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this myself. It'll work if you issue a GO in the client between the drop and the re-create.

Comment: @matt - isn't that just because it reinitializes your connection?

Comment: @JNK I'm not entirely sure. It's not like issuing a GO destroys connection-level temporary tables: `SELECT 'test' AS test INTO #tmp`/`GO`/`SELECT * FROM #tmp` works just fine. (I'm not suggesting GO as a solution here, just trying to figure out what's really going on!)

Comment: Looks like GO is the answer if I insert that both before and after the if object_id portion.  Then the script runs just fine.

Comment: @MattB Well, I'd still not say that's an answer -- (a) I'd love to know what's actually going on here, and (b) that's not going to be much help when defining a stored procedure, say, as the GO will get in the way.